# "FBConnect/FBConnect.h" no such file or directory error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I am developing an iphone application which has some facebook integration in it.I added the **fbconnect** folder which i downlaoded from internet and added `#import "FBConnect/FBConnect.h".`
But when i run the app it shows a lot of errors like

```
  "FBConnect/FBConnect.h" no such file or directory
  "FBConnect/FBsession.h" no such file or directory etc.
```

I downloaded some facebook projects that works fine But what can be the problem with mine?

Comment: do u have specify the header serarchpath?

Comment: @ renuga :no i havnt but the projects i have have seen does not do this .they just put the FBConnect folder in the x-code project and they run fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your header search path is not correct.

In your header search paths write ../src/ & place your facebook connect downloaded source in the same folder in which your project is kept.It should work then.

Comment: ..src/ will only work if you have a Facebook classes folder stored with name of "src"

Comment: I mean whatever is your folder name for facebook

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure if there are other, easier ways, but I do this using the *Header Search Paths* setting (right-click on the target, *Get Info*, select the *Build* tab and filter for *Header*). There you have to enter the path to the Facebook SDK so that the compiler sees the `FBConnect` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution from the above answer for this but i want to give all details about this so others can benifit .

- First download a fbconnect project from [this site](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-fbconnect-facebook-connect-tutorial/)
- Then make your own facebook project and save the downloaded project folder in the same directory as your project
- Then go to **target>get info>Build>header search** and make a new field as **../src(or whatever you name the downloaded project folder)**
- Drag the Fbconnect folder to your xcode and mark the copy check box (It must include the FBConnect bundle)
- Run.